# ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature Error with Rails Sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [rails sortable gem](https://github.com/itmammoth/rails_sortable) to create a table that sorts `goodies` via drag and drop.

I followed the documentation and got this in my view:

```
<main class="container-fluid px-5">
  <header class="text-center">
    <h1 class="thin uppercase">Store Manager</h1>
  </header>

  <section>
    <h2 class="color-spouse font-weight-bold">Product Categories (Goodies)</h2>
    <table id="selectedColumn" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Order</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th># Free</th>
          <th># Paid</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="sortable">
        <% @goodies.each do |g, sortable_id| %>
          <tr id="<%= sortable_id %>">
            <td class="min"><i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i></td>
            <td class="min"><%= g.sort %></td>
            <td><%= g.name %></td>

            <% free = Variation.where(goody_id: g.id).where(price: 0).count %>
            <td><%= free %></td>

            <% paid = Variation.where(goody_id: g.id).where.not(price: 0).count %>
            <td><%= paid %></td>

            <td class="min">
              <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>'.html_safe, edit_goody_path(g), class: "grey-text" %>
              <%= link_to '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>'.html_safe, g, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "grey-text" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

</main>




<%= content_for :additional_js do %>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function() {
        $('.sortable').railsSortable();
      });
    })
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I have this in my controller:

```
def store_manager
    @goodies = Goody.order(:sort).all
    @variations = Variation.order(:sort).all
  end
```

And it does drag and drop as expected.  HOWEVER, when I do so it comes up with this server error:

```
Started POST "/sortable/reorder" for ::1 at 2020-05-18 21:13:47 -0700
Processing by SortableController#reorder as JSON
  Parameters: {"rails_sortable"=>["", "", ""], "sortable"=>{"rails_sortable"=>["", "", ""]}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ /Users/lizbayardelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature - ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature:
```

And then when I refresh the page the new order isn't saved.

I can't see what this has to do with activerecord, as most of that is for blobs and file storage.  Can anyone see why this is triggering this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not submitting the IDs to the backend (as you can tell by the fact that the `rails_sortable` array in the `params` hash contains blank strings in the log output). All that you're missing seems to be to replace `@goodies.each` with `@goodies.each_with_sortable_id` (as the documentation says).

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar error for the blobs!

In my case, 
I had a `Profile` and profile `has_one_attached :profile_image`.

I got this error when I was making changes to the profile object and trying to get the `blob_url` for the `profile_image`.

That's because in backend rails signs every object and when it tried to get the `blob_url`, the signature was changed as I had called `assign_attributes` on the same object.

So I had to separate those two API calls. And it solved my problem.

In your case, 
I guess it's trying to update the columns in the database and fetch the records(which have now changed).

I know, it's not the direct answer but you could find your solution along this line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sandip, exactly I was also doing the same thing and it was not working for me. So, I created a virtual column for this now. It's working fine. The Crux is you cannot modify the same field from which you are getting the data to create or edit the method of rails admin.

Comment: Do you have the code for how you solved it? Thank you so much.